# Change "code" parameter in Microsoft Graph API Redirect Uri

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I am building an Azure Functions application that authenticates with the Microsoft Graph API. I've created a `processCode` function that acts as my redirect URI, which takes the code sent by Graph API to generate the Graph token.

However, Azure Functions use the `code` query string parameter in their calls to pass the function key.

Is it possible for me to configure the Graph API redirect URI to use a different query string parameter other than `code`?

Essentially, changing

```
https://myapp/api/processCode?code=GRAPH-CODE (conflicting code parameter)
```

to

```
https://myapp/api/processCode?code=FUNCTIONS-KEY&graphcode=GRAPH-CODE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. The `code=` query parameter is defined by the OAuth 2.0 specification ([`RFC 6249`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)).

What you might be able to do instead is change your `response_mode` from `query` to `form_post` when you [request the authoirzation code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code). This changes how the code itself gets returned. Rather than issuing a `GET` to your `redirect_uri` with the `code` in the authorization it issues a `POST` to the `redirect_uri` with the `code` in the body (i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

You'd have to adjust your Azure Function to listen for `POST` and parse the content from the body instead of the query string. Otherwise, everything should remain pretty much the same. The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  closely resembles the query string format (`key=value&key=value&etc`).

Comment: Thanks Marc, this is a sound alternative, trying it now. Current blocker is finding where to set the response_mode in the MSAL library but will revert once there are updates.

Comment: I'm not sure MSAL supports `form_post` (read: I can't find it referenced anywhere in the code).

Comment: It does, you just need to add it in the extraQueryParameters field: 

await client.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync(scopes, null, "response_mode=form_post");

Comment: Thank you Marc, this is the correct answer :) I've tested it and gotten it to work successfully.

Another potential answer is to make the function anonymous; this allows the endpoint to be called without passing a code parameter, letting us use it for the Graph Token instead :)